# How to build a security model

Tags: random-oracle-model, adversarial-model

What are the minimal components to build a security model proof for a protocol?

This question might seem trivial, but having read many papers-- from the [IEEE](https://www.ieee.org/), [ACM](https://www.acm.org/), etc., that talk about a [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KMP)-- I still don't know where to start. For example, should I use the adversary model or a random oracle?

Comment: IMHO it depends on the context. Defining a protocol you need to set a context, what is the protocol used for, what is its goal. Then you could define environment (primitives and assumptions) and threats. (TLS has different goal, environment and threats than SAML).

Comment: Although I am sometimes wondering if the choice is correct for crypto.SE or for most sites on the SE network, asking for resources is an *explicit* reason to vote a question off topic. Maybe you could change the question to make it on topic again, e.g. asking what are the minimal components of a security proof.

Comment: Dear Marteen, thank you very much for your suggestion. I modified my question.

Comment: You may want to note that _usually_ the ROM comes in through the proof and not the model / security definition itself.

Comment: To clarify (because you mentioned the ROM): You _are_ asking how to (systematically) construct a security definition for a protocol, right?

Comment: @SEJPM exactly. This one it seems that is not a trivial task.